# Binding multilple list to WPF ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have three list, populated from entity framework, i m trying to display list of ItemType.
    Each element in listbox should be like "TypeName CategoryName ItemTypeDetailName IsActive".

```
Class ItemType has propertis TypeName(string), ItemTypeCategoryId (int), ItemTypeDetailId(int)
Class ItemTypeCategory has propertis ItemTypeCategoryId (int), CategoryName(string)
Class ItemTypeDetail has propertis ItemTypeDetailId (int), ItemTypeDetailName(string)
```

I try to use IValueConvertor.
How to create this binding?

Comment: Perhaps an `interface` might be useful here?

Comment: Create new class like ListboxItemViewModel with properties which you want to display later create single list of that class, fill it with values from three other and bind it to ListBox

Comment: Why don't select projection from database, which will be suitable to display? Another option is to make navigation properties in your entity models.

Comment: Thanks, but i am using entity framework, so cant use interface. Also is there is any to to do this without ViewModel as my project is not  MVVM based

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

ViewModels:

```
public interface IItemType
{
    object Item1{ get; set; }
    object Item2{ get; set; }
    object Item3{ get; set; }
}

public class ItemType : IItemType
{
    public int ItemTypeCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int ItemTypeDetailId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public object Item1
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemTypeCategoryId;
        }
        set
        {
            ItemTypeCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
    public object Item2
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemTypeDetailId;
        }
        set
        {
            ItemTypeDetailId = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
    public object Item3
    {
        get
        {
            return TypeName;
        }
        set
        {
            TypeName = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class ItemTypeCategory : IItemType
{
    public int ItemTypeCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public object Item1
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemTypeCategoryId;
        }
        set
        {
            ItemTypeCategoryId = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
    public object Item2
    {
        get
        {
            return CategoryName;
        }
        set
        {
            CategoryName = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    public object Item3{ get; set; }

}

public class ItemTypeDetail : IItemType
{
    public int ItemTypeDetailId { get; set; }
    public string ItemTypeDetailName { get; set; }

    public object Item1
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemTypeDetailId;
        }
        set
        {
            ItemTypeDetailId = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        }
    }
    public object Item2
    {
        get
        {
            return ItemTypeDetailName;
        }
        set
        {
            ItemTypeDetailName = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    public object Item3 {get;set;}

}
```

Main window:

```
    public List<IItemType> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        IItemType i1 = new ItemType { ItemTypeCategoryId = 1, ItemTypeDetailId = 2, TypeName = "ItemType1" };
        IItemType i2 = new ItemTypeCategory { ItemTypeCategoryId = 2, CategoryName = "ItemTypeCategory1" };
        IItemType i3 = new ItemTypeDetail { ItemTypeDetailId = 3, ItemTypeDetailName = "ItemTypeDetail1" };

        Items = new List<IItemType>();

        Items.Add(i1);
        Items.Add(i2);
        Items.Add(i3);
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Window>
    <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Item1}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Item2}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Item3}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```